# Difference between jQuery's .on('click') vs .click()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Could someone please help me to understand the difference between these two jQuery functions?

```
$('#theElement').click(function() {
    ... click handler code ...
});
```

AND

```
$('body').on('click', '#theElement', function() {
    .... click handler code ...
});
```

According to [jQuery's documentation](http://api.jquery.com/click/), `.click()` is just a shortcut for `.on('click')`. And that's the way I've always found it to work. However, I noticed a key difference when building out a prototype today. I could not use `.click()` when trying to assign an even listener to an element that wasn't yet in the DOM. However, if I did it with `$('body').on('click', '#theElement'...`, it worked!

Trying to understand why...

Does the `.on()` have something to do with event capturing that `.click()` does not?

Thank you to whoever can help point me in the right direction. This is driving me nuts!

Comment: What the documentation actually says is that `.click()` is a shortcut for `.on("click", handler)`. So that's the signature you need to look at in the `.on()` docs.

Comment: is pretty well documented on `on()` API

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of event delegation: http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.click()` is an alias of `.trigger('click')`, while `.click(data, fn)` is an alias of `.on('click', null, data, fn)`.

You might not pass in a second argument, in which case, `.on('click', null, data, fn)` will still bind the handler using `data` as the handler instead of `fn`.

Additionally, what this means is that there's no way to assign a delegate via [`.click(...)`](http://api.jquery.com/click/), so if you need event delegation you should use [`.on(...)`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

From the latest [source](http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js):

<sub>jQuery v1.10.2, lines 7554-7564:</sub>

```
jQuery.each( ("blur focus focusin focusout load resize scroll unload click dblclick " +
    "mousedown mouseup mousemove mouseover mouseout mouseenter mouseleave " +
    "change select submit keydown keypress keyup error contextmenu").split(" "), function( i, name ) {

    // Handle event binding
    jQuery.fn[ name ] = function( data, fn ) {
        return arguments.length > 0 ?
            this.on( name, null, data, fn ) :
            this.trigger( name );
    };
});
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer the question. This makes a lot more sense - didn't realize that the delegate argument was `null` when using `.click(...)` - that makes a ton more sense. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Apart from what they have in common:

- `.click()` can trigger a click event

  > Description: Bind an event handler to the "click" JavaScript event, **or trigger** that event on an element.
- `.on()` uses delegation, which means you can target/attach events to dynamic created content (as long as the .on() method is applied to a parent element present when the code is run

  > Description: Attach an event handler function for one or more events to the selected elements.[...] *A bit more down the page:* Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from descendant elements **that are added to the document at a later time**.

Comment: Note that `.on` doesn't add event handlers to dynamic elements. It binds the handler to the elements that are selected. If a selector is provided as argument then the handler is executed only when the event originated from an element that matches the selector.

Comment: @FelixKling, correct correct. Made a edit trying to be more clear.